# Fill an array using a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to fill an array with my foreach loop, but I don't get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
$a = array();

$activities = Project::getProjectnames($_DB, $projectnaam);
if(!empty($activities)) {
    foreach($activities as $k => $v) {
          $a .= array_fill($v['name']);
    }
}
```

All I get back is the string `Array`...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you're concatenating a string there. You need to push the item into the array.

```
   foreach($activities as $k => $v) {
          $a[] = $v['name'];
    }
```